# Condition handling the smart way

Tags: java

```
if (lineStyle == 5 || lineStyle == 21 || lineStyle == 82 || lineStyle == 83 || lineStyle == 3) {
    lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";
} else if (lineStyle == 6 || lineStyle == 35 || lineStyle == 39 || lineStyle == 30) {
    lineStyleString = "DOTTED" ;
} else if (lineStyle == 26 || lineStyle == 27  || lineStyle == 28  || lineStyle == 29 || lineStyle == 1) {
    lineStyleString = "SOLID";
} else if(lineStyle == -1) {
    lineStyleString = "NONE";
}
```

How do we handle this code the smart way in Java? Switch case, enum or key pair value mode?

Comment: All your magic numbers look completely random. The "smart way" to do this depends very much on how they're structured.

Comment: if the compiler is smart enough and the values are literals as shown, a `switch()` will very likely be the most efficient choice.

Answer (score 6):

Your conditions looks more random.

Switch looks good here

```
switch(lineStyle) {
    case 5:
    case 21:
    case 82:
    case 83:
    case 3: 
     lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";   
     break;
    .. // add more cases
}
```

---

Or I prefer to create utility method

```
public static boolean contains(int expecxted, int... vals) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            if (expecxted == vals[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And you can use it like

```
if (contains(lineStyle, 5,21,82,83,3)) {
    lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";
} else if(contains(lineStyle,6,35,39,30)){
   lineStyleString = "DOTTED";
}
```

Comment: It takes 30 lines ^^

Comment: @azro but much more efficient (time/memory), if that matters

Comment: @azro 30 lines that are trivial for any programmer to understand both the function and the intent are much better than 10 lines that require mental work to understand.

Comment: @azro Switches are there for a reason and I more prefer readability.

Comment: @azro:  This isn't code golf.  This is about making code more readable.  All of these approaches accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 3):

A switch case well-indented would take **30** lines (Netbeans proposed to transform it by itself so I could count)

So I would consider this way is better (**9** lines) :

```
if (Arrays.asList(5, 21, 82, 83, 3).contains(lineStyle)) {
     lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";
} else if (Arrays.asList(6, 35, 39, 30).contains(lineStyle)) {
     lineStyleString = "DOTTED";
} else if (Arrays.asList(26, 27, 28, 29, 1).contains(lineStyle)) {
     lineStyleString = "SOLID";
}else if (lineStyle == -1) {
     lineStyleString = "NONE";
}
```

Comment: maybe consider creating constants for the arrays... with a meaningful names, so it's easier to understand/maintain

Comment: I feel the performance of this idea is too horrible - to construct dynamic arrays of constants just to achieve a simple switch seems overly complicated both from a human readable and computation point of view.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Also it would prevent the creation of too many objects.

Comment: @QBrute that's one of the reason I suggested it, just thought that's kind of clear

Comment: Which one is better when compared with performance. Switch, Arrays.asList(Constant) or enum

Comment: The difference of performance is count here in nano-sec so .. as you want

Comment: @user1023675 if this is repeated very very often, switch is the better one in terms of velocity: switch uses a jump-table (or so) while Arrays.asList is creating a List and searching the list... but normally this will not be a factor, readability and so maintainability should much more be a concern!

Comment: I agree that performance are lower for mine but even if you run it 8 000 000 times, it'd takes less than 1sec ^^ So let the user choose if he need to win some nano-sec (1/1.000.000millisec) of just do it in a few lines, stop debate for me

Answer (score 2):

I prefer an enum like:

```
enum LineStyle {

  DOUBLE(3, 5, 21, 82, 83),
  DOTTED(6, 30, 35, 39),
  SOLID(1, 26, 27, 28, 29),
  NONE(-1);

  private final Set<Integer> types;

  private LineStyle(Integer... types) {
    this.types = Stream.of(types).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }

  public static LineStyle of(int lineStyle) {
    return Stream.of(LineStyle.values())
      .filter(ls -> ls.types.contains(lineStyle))
      .findFirst().orElse(null);
  }
}
```

Then you can simply call: `LineStyle ls = LineStyle.of(lineStyle);`

Comment: Which one is better when compared with performance. Switch, Arrays.asList(Constant) or enum

Comment: It's up to you to test it. I would rank it `switch/if` < `Map` < `enum` < `Arrays.asList` (whereby switch is the fastest)

Comment: @Flown actually switch should be (slightly) faster than if since it usually is just an indexed jump. not sure how the JIT compiler influences that...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Again this has to be tested :)

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the conditions into methods to make them more readable.

```
private boolean isDoubleStyle(int lineStyle) {
    return lineStyle == 5 || lineStyle == 21 || lineStyle == 82 || lineStyle == 83 || lineStyle == 3;
}

private boolean isDottedStyle(int lineStyle) {
    return lineStyle == 6 || lineStyle == 35 || lineStyle == 39 || lineStyle == 30;
}

private boolean isSolidStyle(int lineStyle) {
    return lineStyle == 26 || lineStyle == 27  || lineStyle == 28  || lineStyle == 29 || lineStyle == 1;
}
```

and then call the methods

```
if (isDoubleStyle(lineStyle)) {
    lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";
} else if (isDottedStyle(lineStyle)) {
    lineStyleString = "DOTTED" ;
} else if (isSolidStyle(lineStyle)) {
    lineStyleString = "SOLID";
} else {
    lineStyleString = "NONE";
}
```

I removed the final check for `linestyle == -1` to ensure that `lineStyleString` always has a value, no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

You could prepopulate a `Map<Integer, String>` and save it somewhere, then use that to determine your value without a conditional check. Like,

```
Map<Integer, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of(5, 21, 82, 83, 3).forEach(x -> valueMap.put(x, "DOUBLE"));
Stream.of(6, 35, 39, 30).forEach(x -> valueMap.put(x, "DOTTED"));
Stream.of(26, 27, 28, 29, 1).forEach(x -> valueMap.put(x, "SOLID"));
valueMap.put(-1, "NONE");
```

and then later

```
String lineStyleString = valueMap.get(lineStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
switch (lineStyle){
    case 5:
    case 21:
    case 82:
    case 83:
    case 3:
        lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";
        break;
    ...
```

Comment: It takes 30 lines

Comment: what's the difference to [Suresh's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164058/85421), despite 5 minutes later?

Comment: No difference. Sorry, his answer appeared right after I had sent mine, I was writing it with one hand while working.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to use the switch statement.

```
int lcase = lineStyle;
String lineStyleString = null;
switch(lcase)
{
    case 3 :
    case 5 :
    case 21:
    case 82:
    case 83:
        lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";
        break;
    case 6 :
    case 30:
    case 35:
    case 39:
        lineStyleString = "DOTTED";
        break;
    case 1 :
    case 26:
    case 27:
    case 28:
    case 29:
        lineStyleString = "SOLID";
        break;
    case -1:
        lineStyleString = "NONE";
        break;         
}
```

Comment: what's the difference to first part of [Suresh's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164058/85421), despite 9 minutes later?

Comment: I hate lazy typing, the question was easy to pick by any coder. But he did not even think to write the complete answer.

Comment: really? then, speaking about being lazy: his indentation is correct, he has not included normal text in the code section, not using additional unneeded variables... and the sample he posted should be enough to understand the idea - StackOverflow is not a site to do complete coding, it's to answer questions.

Answer (score -1):

Do not know if this is the smart way but it is definetly more readable and short:

```
lineStyleString = (lineStyle == 5 || lineStyle == 21 || lineStyle == 82 || lineStyle == 83 || lineStyle == 3)? "DOUBLE"
                    :(lineStyle == 6 || lineStyle == 35 || lineStyle == 39 || lineStyle == 30)? "DOTTED"
                    :(lineStyle == 26 || lineStyle == 27  || lineStyle == 28  || lineStyle == 29 || lineStyle == 1)? "SOLID"
                    :"NONE";
```

or using IntStream

```
   lineStyleString = (IntStream.of(5,21,82,83,3).anyMatch(x -> x == lineStyle)) ? "DOUBLE"
                    :(IntStream.of(6,35,39,30).anyMatch(x -> x == lineStyle))   ? "DOTTED"
                    :(IntStream.of(26,27,28,29,1).anyMatch(x -> x == lineStyle))? "SOLID"
                    :"NONE";
```

Answer (score -2):

With some trivial reformatting it's fine as-is:

```
int s = lineStyle;

if (s == 5 || s == 21 || s == 82 || s == 83 || s == 3) {
    lineStyleString = "DOUBLE";

} else if (s == 6 || s == 35 || s == 39 || s == 30) {
    lineStyleString = "DOTTED";

} else if (s == 26 || s == 27  || s == 28  || s == 29 || s == 1) {
    lineStyleString = "SOLID";

} else if (s == -1) {
    lineStyleString = "NONE";
}
```